# Does the Weierstrass M-test apply if a term of the functional series is undefined on the domain of definition?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm analysing the series of functions $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{x\cdot n^2}-1} \qquad \textrm{where  } \space x \geq 0$$ for uniform convergence. I'm trying to use the Weierstrass M-test so I picked a convergent upper bound of $\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{n^2} }$ which holds when $x\geq 1$, i.e: $$\left|\frac{1}{e^{n^2x}-1}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right| \space \textrm{for  } x\geq1, $$ and we know that $$\zeta (2) = \sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty} {\frac 1 {n^2}} = \frac {\pi^2} {6} < \infty$$

However, when $x \in [0;1)$, I'm unsure since the value is undefined when $x=0$. Does this imply that the series of functions is thus not uniformly convergent for $x \geq 0$, but *is* uniformly convergent for $x \gt 0$? Or are we supposed to only focus only on what happens in the limit?

Comment: Note the series is undefined for $x=0.$

Comment: @zhw. that is primarily what my question is about.

Comment: Clearly $x= 0$ makes no sense. I would ssume the domain is $(0,\infty).$

Comment: I did notice that including 0 in the domain is problematic which is why I presented the question asking about both cases; when $x \in [0;1)$ and when $x \in (0;1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $X,$ then $\sup_X |f_n|\to 0.$ Is that true for the given series on $X=(0,\infty)?$?

Comment: From my understanding, using the same upper bound we can claim that the supremum is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ which tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The $1/n^2$ business works for $[1,\infty),$ but I am concerned with $(0,1).$

Comment: It seems to me that when $x$ is close to $0$, and for a fixed $n \geq 1$, the functions tend to infinity and thus aren't less than $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Not less than $1/n^2$ doesn't tell you very much.  What we have is $\sup_{(0,1)} f_n = \infty,$ and therefore from my hint, the series can't converge uniformly there.

Comment: Got it, thanks! But what about in the general case where there is an undefined term in the domain. Does that immediately imply that the functional series isn't uniformly convergent on the given set?

Comment: No, because things like $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n(1/x)}{n^2}$$ do converge uniformly in $(0,1).$